# What does .self do in this context?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm working on a project and I have no idea as to what the *self.* does in this context:

```
  def owner_is?(user)
    self.user_id == user.id
  end
```

I understand what def self.method does, as it's a class method but not how it's used above.

Why might someone use self.user_id like in the context above, what is that doing? My guess is, self is referring to the current_user?

Please help clear this up for me,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will refer to the model instance that this method is being called on.

Comment: So in this case, it's referring to an instance of the Event object. As it's being called with the Event.rb model. I think I got it? Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

`self` refers to the current instance of whatever you're looking at.

Here it calls the instance's `user_id` method, which might be:

1. Different than @user_id, and/or since this is tagged Rails, ...
2. ...different than the attribute access "raw" via whatever underlying mechanism like `attributes[sym]`, bypassing the generated or your own accessors.

Is it a *significant* difference? It really depends. The *safest* bet is to prefix persisted field accessors with `self` to ensure you're getting what you think you are, particularly if you override any of those accessors.

I don't always do this when it's not an assignment, but there is an associated risk.

Answer (score 3):

**self** refers to the current instance of a model. It is use for call method and attributes for current model.

Answer (score 0):

`.self` is reffering to the object it is being called on.

Comment: Cheers! Doesn't it automatically refer to the object by default - since the code is written in the Event.rb model?

Comment: @user3399101 Yes. But you have to make sure you're calling the method you actually think you are, which is why I commented about persisted attributes.